# SmartBreadcrumb services.UseBreadcrumb not found. New to breadcrumbs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, breadcrumbs

I am new to all this.

I am using Visual Studio 2019, c# and .Core 5 to write a web application.

I am trying to add a breadcrumb trail.  After looking on the internet I installed the Nuget package SmartBreadcrumbs.

I then added the following code to my ConfigureServices in startUp.cs -

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.UseBreadCrumbs(GetType().Assembly, options =>
   {
      TagName = "nav";
      TagClasses = "";
      OlClasses = "breadcrumb";
      LiClasses = "breadcrumb-item";
      ActiveLiClasses = "breadcrumb-item active";
      SeparatorElement = "<li class=\"separator\">/</li>";
   });
```

The code doesn't like UseBreadCrumbs.

Can someone help please.

I have tried adding

```
using SmartBreadcrumbs;
```

Nothing

[UPDATE]
I have tried the following -

```
[HttpGet]
[Breadcrumb("Designations", FromAction = "RecordOfDesignations", FromPage = typeof(VaccinationClinicController))]
public IActionResult RecordOfDesignations(int id)
{
   if (id <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(id));
   
   var vaccinationCentre = _vaccinationClinicRepository.GetVaccinationById(id).Result;
    
   var viewModel = new DesignationListViewModel();
    
                
 _designationControllerHelper.PopulateDesignationListViewModel(viewModel, vaccinationCentre);
    
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The Default Breadcrumb is in the vaccination controller -

```
[HttpGet]
[DefaultBreadcrumb("YFVC List")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page)
{
    page ??= 1;

    var vaccClinicListViewModel = await _vaccinationClinicListService.GetPagedListing(PageSize, page);
            var trainingNumberOfDays = _dueWithinDaysRepository.GetDueWithinDaysByWhatIsToBeRenewed("Training").Result.NumberOfDays;

    viewBag.NumberOfDays = _dueWithinDaysRepository.GetDueWithinDaysByWhatIsToBeRenewed("Designation").Result.NumberOfDays;
    ViewBag.TrainingNumberOfDays = trainingNumberOfDays;

    return View("Index", vaccClinicListViewModel);
}
```

IT seems to hang now when trying to go to the designations page.  IT works without the breadcrumbs.

I am banging my head of a wall!!

Comment: I think it should be  services.AddBreadCrumbs...

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins.  That worked.  However I am getting another error now.  It is saying that my controller doesn't have an index.  I added the attribute [Breadcrumb("Controller")] to an Get method in the controller.  I have a DefaultBreadcrumb attribute in another controller.  Does it have to be ona method called index?

Comment: Check the docs: https://github.com/zHaytam/SmartBreadcrumbs